# Getting file modification time on UNIX using utime in C

Tags: c, file, unix, unix-timestamp

I have been told by a professor that you can get a file's last modification time by using **utime.h**. However, the man page seem to cite that **utime()** only sets this value. How can I look up the last time a file was changed in C on a UNIX system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This returns the file's *mtime*, the "time of last data modification". Note that [Unix](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) also has a concept *ctime*, the "time of last status change"  (see also [ctime, atime, mtime](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/ctime_atime_mtime.html)).

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

time_t get_mtime(const char *path)
{
    struct stat statbuf;
    if (stat(path, &statbuf) == -1) {
        perror(path);
        exit(1);
    }
    return statbuf.st_mtime;
}
```

Comment: @AldySyahdeini `localtime(3)`

Comment: This was answered in 2010 but it's 2016 now and nanosecond resolution has been implemented since Linux kernel 2.5.48, POSIX.1-2008 and glibc 2.12. So using `statbuf.st_mtim` to get a `struct timespec` instead of using `statbuf.st_mtime` should work everwhere these days.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**stat**](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/stat.html) system call to get the last access and modification times.