# Updating status of a growing file without close/reopen

Tags: c, linux, file-handling

Suppose I `open()` a file on a *nix machine and I hit `eof`. But when I `open()`ed it, it was still being written.

Is there a way to detect if the file has grown since `open()`-time? Or do I need to `close()` and re-`open()` to check?

Is there a way to read past the old `eof` without `close()`ing and re`open()`ing?

Comment: What about checking the mtime and see if that's later than when you opened the file?   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021479/getting-file-modification-time-on-unix-using-utime-in-c

Comment: And, possibly a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087204/how-can-i-tell-if-a-file-is-open-elsewhere-in-c-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

Although not portable, on linux you can use the inotify system and watch for file close events for your file of interest.  See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-inotify/.

Note that just because the file was closed by the other process doesn't necessarily mean its size has increased.  If you care about file size changes, use `stat()` to check for size changes before you close it.  See [How do you determine the size of a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c)